# Inverse PDF Search in beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex, pdf, forward-inverse-search

Can you please help in fixing a problem with inverse PDF search in beamer documents

beamer does not work correctly with SyncTeX. Inverse PDF search (in Sumatra, Texworks, etc. I’ve tried all windows options) shows only the end of a frame, not the line with corresponding code.

So if you have 30 pages in [allowframebreaks], inverse PDF search is useless.

Any suggestions?

Is it possible to insert some commands like line numbering to create inverse search points in beamer?

Comment: I guess that's one of the reasons why Till Tantau considers `allowframebreaks` as *evil*.

Comment: It's probably possible, but would take a fair bit of effort to reimplement various functionalities in beamer. I have a question on this [luatex - How can I capture and rescan TeX source code while preserving synctex data? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631887/how-can-i-capture-and-rescan-tex-source-code-while-preserving-synctex-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 10):

The `beamer` class works by reading the input and typesetting in a manner reminiscent of verbatim. Regrettably, that means that the hook for SyncTeX is at the end of a frame, and not as the source is written. There is not much that can be done about this.