# synctex and fragile beamer's frame

Tags: beamer, listings, forward-inverse-search

I'm using `synctex` on a `beamer` presentation, and I'm having some trouble. Unlike [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20662/inverse-pdf-search-in-beamer), I can live with the fact that `synctex` will put me at the end of the current frame. However, for `fragile` frames, I end up in `slides.vrb`, which basically contains the last `fragile` frame of the presentation.

`fragile` frames without overlays are OK, as the `fragile=singleslide` option will make `synctex` find the appropriate line, but some of my `fragile` frames have several overlays. Is there something that can be done for them?

**Update:** As a matter of fact, the issue seems to only occurs when using `listings`. Here is a way to reproduce the problem (Note that it assumes that you have configured your pdf viewer, `okular` in my case, to be able to perform an inverse search to your editor, `emacs` in my case).

Consider the following `slide.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{title}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}
bar

\lstinline|bla|
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

1. Compile it with `synctex` enabled: `pdflatex -synctex=1 slide.tex`
2. open `slide.pdf` with a `synctex`-aware viewer: `okular slide.pdf`
3. perform an inverse search (<kbd>shift</kbd>+click in `okular`) on `bar`: it should move the cursor of your editor at the end of the frame as expected.
4. perform an inverse search on `foo`, which is in an `lstlisting` environment: it should open the auxiliary `slide.vrb` file in your editor and point you there instead of `slide.tex`.
5. The same issue occurs with `\lstinline|bla|`: if you <kbd>shift</kbd>+click on `bla`, it opens `slide.vrb`.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @samcarter I was under the impression that your comment was a little bit stereotypical, but in the end, it made me realize that `synctex`, `beamer` and `fragile` were not the only needed ingredients to the issue and that you had to throw in `listings` as well. Thus thank you for forcing me to be a bit more rigorous in my description.

Comment: There's not much you can do, I'm afraid. SyncTeX takes note of the file where the input is coming from and, for a `fragile` frame, the file `\jobname.vrb` is used. So that's the one which is opened, but of course it changes every time `fragile` is found.

Comment: @egreg Maybe convert your comment into an answer? It might not solve the OP's problem, but it explains why.

Comment: @samcarter I'm not sure about it; it seems that `listings` is doing something strange: I get a mysterious “Successfully formatted [0] pages” with the OP's example. Overlays clearly are out of the question, as it's impossible to keep track of the multiple `\input{\jobname.vrb}`.