VS Code and Beamer : click on PDF opens vrb file instead of tex file
Every so often, while working on Beamer documents in VS Code, clicking on some page in a PDF output in VS Code takes me to the .vrb file instead of the .tex file.
I am using LaTeX Workshop by James Yu, and (as far as I know) no conflicting extensions.
Is there a fix for this?

Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456617/beamer-what-is-purpose-of-vrb-files?noredirect=1&lq=1

Thanks! A related post is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340292/synctex-and-fragile-beamers-frame. It would appear that a solution does not exist yet.

The easiest workaround is to click in the frame below or above. This should get you close to the source.

But what if there are 3 consecutive fragile frames?

... then you are at most 2 frames away. If your tex code is indented and/or you editor highlights environment, scrolling two frames up- or down should be quick.
